# Wordpress not opening with cellular data in mobile phone

Tags: wordpress, mobile, woocommerce

I have a wordpress site with woocommerce installed, It was hosted on hostgator linux shared server but I migrated it from hostgator to Godaddy linux shared server.
When I try to open my site on any mobile with any cellular data it doesn't open and gives error after 2-3 min: **This Site can't be reached**

On other hand when I open same link with any Wifi network with same mobile device or different device, It works fine.

Can anyone help me to fix this.

I tried uninstalling all plugins but got the same results.

Note: It was working fine earlier on hostgator hosting.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1: Change your IPv4 DNS address

[click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E6fU.png)

Method 2: Get help with a VPN

Try Hola VPN chrome extension or hotspot shield VPN extension

Comment: It works with VPN only, why so? How can i make it normal to work with all mobile cellular data?

Comment: The way things look to me is that it is one of two different things, both of which are something you will probably need to contact GoDaddy to resolve.  It sounds to me that there is some IP Blocking going on with your site whenever u accessing using cellular network .  There could also be some filtering going on in GoDaddy's network somewhere.  Unfortunately, in either case, it's probably something that they need to fix.

Comment: No it’s not like that, I just putted a .exe file on same wordpress directory and try to download it with direct link, it was working fine, there must be some issue with wordpress, files apart from wordpress are accessible with direct link